# How do I assign a Launchpad bug to an external tracker?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

I have encountered an application issue that I know has a bug assigned in both [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rabbitvcs/+bug/859104) and the [external tracker](http://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/issues/detail?id=566) the application project actually uses (in this case Google Code). I understand that [Launchpad can integrate with external trackers](https://launchpad.net/+tour/bugs) (and can see an example assigned against another package in this bug).

I have a Launchpad login. I can click on the pencil icon next to the status to change it (for example, change to "Confirmed") but I don't get an option to associate the bug with an external issue, which is what I actually want to do. Do I not have permission to, or is there some other option that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an "Also affects project" link on the bug which would allow you to link to the rabbitvcs project on launchpad.

[image]

As you are adding it from the context of the rabbitvcs ubuntu package, it will automatically select the upstream rabbitvcs project on launchpad & allow you to paste in the URL.

[image]